# Help explaining some C++ code I haven't seen before

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, c++

I'm studying for the upcoming pr review club.

```
        if (!m_foreign_outputs.empty()) {
             std::string s(m_foreign_outputs.size(), 0);
             for (auto i = m_foreign_outputs.size(); i--; ) {
                 if (m_foreign_outputs.at(i)) {
                     s[i / 8] |= 1 << (i % 8);
                 }
             }
             mapValueCopy["fout"] = s;
         }
```

What is that for loop doing? and how is it not stuck forever?
Also what is happening here:

`s[i / 8] |= 1 << (i % 8);`

Thanks!

Comment: I understand the loop now, I haven't seen that before, I guess it walks through the vector from the highest index to the lowest and exits the loop after zero. That's cool. I'm lost on the string, it looks like it is creating some sort of unicode values?

Comment: Thank you, I guessed that when I woke up today but definitely wasn't sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better asked in the review club, or on the PR.

Comment: I'm voting to close this topic, because it's a question about the C++ programming language.

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a string where each character value is composed of bits representing 8 booleans from m_foreign_values packed together.